# Null Pointer at Textview

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

The answer may be staring right at me but I just can't see it!

Am getting a null pointer exception when setting the text on a Textview with a string from a ArrayList of Strings. Have initialised everything and checked the ArrayLiist has data, everything seems to check out. But when the textview is been declared in onCreate() I can see in the debugger the value remains null.

OnCreate():

private TextView title;

```
//onCreate()
```

setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

```
 imageNames = new ArrayList<String>();
       title = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_imageDescriptionGallery);


      setImageAndTitleArrays();


      //check size of arrays and build correctly
      Log.d("GALLERY VIEW:" , "IMaegNaem array Size: "+imageNames.size() + " Image Array Size: "+ bitmapArray.size());

      Log.d("GALLERYVIEW: ", "First Image Name of Array: "+ imageNames.get(0));

      //set default image title and description, we will update every tome a image clicked


//exception throne here as title=null on debugger
      title.setText(imageNames.get(0));
```

The textview :

```
 <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/tv_imageDescriptionGallery"
          android:layout_margin="20dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:text="Image Name"
          android:textColor="#55bbfa"


         />....
```

Gallery XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background2">

   <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Astro Gallery"
         android:textColor="#55bbfa"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splitter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sample_note"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/splitter" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera1" />

         <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/tv_imageDescriptionGallery"
          android:layout_margin="20dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:text="Image Name"
          android:textColor="#55bbfa"


         />



           <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Set Wallpaper"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

          <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />



 </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you ever call `setContextView()` with the layout that your `TextView` is in?

Comment: Check exactly what is null at that line while debugging.

Comment: @AndrewSchuster you mean `setContentView()`, right?

Comment: is the textView in the same layout as declared as in setContentView()?

Comment: Yep setContentView is there, have added above.

Comment: Do you have a fragment or only activity?

Comment: When the debugger passes the title (Textview ) assignment to the Textview in xml, title remains null whilst all other buttons and widgets are fine.

Comment: I hope textview is in layout gallery. Try cleaning your project. It happens with me sometimes when I modify views in xml.

Comment: post the complete xml of the layout where the textview is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I checked all the imports, removed all the ref to 'this, rename the class and all refs to it,  cleaned and build, could not resolve the NPE.

I deleted the class and xml from the project, then made a new class and xml file with same code and worked fine.

I had a class with exact same name in a separate project, not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: So maybe this was an IDE problem after all ... had you reboot it ? Did you clean the project ? I know it's over, just curious ;)

Comment: Rebooted, cleaned, renamed class/XML nothing worked until i deleted and repopulated both class an xml . Before this issue I had two classes with identical names from different projects opened.....after I saved and closed the IDE then opened next day I had the issue...must be IDE related some cross reference betwern the classss in diff projects

Answer (score 1):

Only 2 hypothesis : 
Maybe you tried to import R.java and you imported the wrong one ? 
Or try to remove "this" in front of findViewById?

The 2 only ideas that come to mind, hope it can help.

Comment: The `import` statements aren't the issue because it would probably result in a compile time error plus the other views work. `this` is not needed but isn't a factor since it refers to the activity and `findViewById()` is an `Activity` method.

Comment: checked all imports and removed all this statements. Cant understand it at all